# How to use WifiManager with Adafruit IO?

Tags: arduino, wifimanager, adafruit

I'm using Adafruit IO and trying to incorporate it with WifiManager so I don't have to hard code the wifi credentials however i'm getting this error when I set the wifi_ssid and wifi_pass to null and rely on wifimanager to connect. When I set the credentials everything works smoothly. How do I use adafruit IO with wifimanager?

```
Connecting to Adafruit IOGuru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled.
20:26:54.512 -> Core 1 register dump:
20:26:54.512 -> PC      : 0x400e1c82  PS      : 0x00060c30  A0      : 0x800e12f1  A1      : 0x3ffb1d30  
20:26:54.512 -> A2      : 0x3ffc17a8  A3      : 0x3f400196  A4      : 0xfffffc7f  A5      : 0x00002180  
20:26:54.512 -> A6      : 0x00002000  A7      : 0x3ffc1ae4  A8      : 0x00000000  A9      : 0x3ffb1d10  
20:26:54.560 -> A10     : 0x00000019  A11     : 0x3f400196  A12     : 0x00000019  A13     : 0x0000ff00  
20:26:54.560 -> A14     : 0x00ff0000  A15     : 0xff000000  SAR     : 0x0000001c  EXCCAUSE: 0x0000001c  
20:26:54.560 -> EXCVADDR: 0x00000000  LBEG    : 0x400014fd  LEND    : 0x4000150d  LCOUNT  : 0xfffffff9  
20:26:54.560 -> 
20:26:54.560 -> ELF file SHA256: 0000000000000000
20:26:54.560 -> 
20:26:54.560 -> Backtrace: 0x400e1c82:0x3ffb1d30 0x400e12ee:0x3ffb1d50 0x400d1615:0x3ffb1d70 0x400e5156:0x3ffb1fb0 0x4008ab7a:0x3ffb1fd0
20:26:54.560 -> 
20:26:54.560 -> Rebooting...
20:26:54.606 -> ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57
```

Arduino Code

```
#include <WiFiManager.h>
#include "config.h"

AdafruitIO_Feed *lamp = io.feed("lamp");

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  Serial.println("Booting Up");
  
  //WIFI STUFF
  bool res;
  
  WiFiManager wifiManager;
  res = wifiManager.autoConnect("lamp");

  if(!res) {
        Serial.println("Failed to connect");
        // ESP.restart();
    } 
    else {
        //if you get here you have connected to the WiFi    
        Serial.println("connected...yeey :)");
    }
   //END WIFI STUFF

//start connecting to Adafruit IO
  Serial.print("Connecting to Adafruit IO");
  io.connect();

}
```

config.h

```
//get this info from the "My Key" section of the Adafruit IO website
#define IO_USERNAME  "XXX"
#define IO_KEY       "XXX"

// ***************************IGNORE ALL BELOW THIS**********************************
#include "AdafruitIO_WiFi.h"

AdafruitIO_WiFi io(IO_USERNAME, IO_KEY, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: move `lamp = io.feed("lamp");` into setup(). let the pointer `AdafruitIO_Feed *lamp;` above setup()

Comment: that didnt work. same issue

Answer (score 0):

Using the current or relatively recent version of the AdafruitIO library you can call like this to avoid the Adafruit library from connecting to WiFi...

```
AdafruitIO_WiFi io(IO_USERNAME, IO_KEY, "", "");
```

Comment: Answer code part needs formatting